# position: relative; position: absolute; in drop down list

Tags: html, css

At https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp
It puts

```
position: relative;
position: absolute;
```

for

```
.dropdown
.dropdown-content
```

respectively.

I removed them as follows and seems it still works, are they important?

```css
.dropdown {    
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;     
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't add it, it will shift the next elements.

```css
.position-relative{
  position:relative;
}

.position-absolute{
  position:absolute;
}

.dropdown {    
  margin-left:30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;     
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown position-relative">
  <span>Relative Position</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content position-absolute">
      <p>Absolute Position</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>No shift</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>Hi</div>
```

By using `position:absolute` inside a `position:relative` element, you can set the position of the inner div depending on the outer one.

```css
.outer{
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  background-color:orange;
}
.inner{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}
.position-relative{
  position:relative;
}
.blue{
  background-color:blue;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer position-relative">
  <div class="inner red"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you had something under dropdown with `position: relative` and `position: absolute` the dropdown will appear on top of it. If you remove it then the dropdown will appear in between and push the content after itself to the bottom.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; /*try commenting this line*/
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below to open the dropdown content.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Under dropdown<p>

</body>
</html>
```