# How can I create a hover div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you go to https://www.handy.com/ and hover over the All Services link, you'll be able to see a overlay with a bunch of categories.

How can I do this so that it's SEO friendly?

See image attached

[image]

Comment: does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72168920/position-relative-position-absolute-in-drop-down-list/72168989#72168989) or [this pen](https://codepen.io/cedricbeausseron/pen/PoQGZBO) answer your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure it like this, which in my opinion would be the most semantically correct. Just because everything is wrapped in a `<div>`, it doesn't mean it doesn't have semantic value. As long as the child elements have the proper HTML-structuring it's fine.

```css
div>nav>ul>li {
  font-size: 25px;
}

nav>ul>li>ul>li {
font-size: 15px;
}

div>nav {
  display: none;
}

div:hover nav {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div><span>menu</span>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><span>category 1</span>
        <ul>
          <li><a>item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>item 3</a></li>
          <li><a>item 4</a></li>
          <li><a>item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>category 2</span>
        <ul>
          <li><a>item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>item 3</a></li>
          <li><a>item 4</a></li>
          <li><a>item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>category 3</span>
        <ul>
          <li><a>item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>item 3</a></li>
          <li><a>item 4</a></li>
          <li><a>item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```